# Get only the next 6 characters after a word

Tags: php

I have this string:

`$string = 'foo bar php haystack needle'`

And i want to get the next 6 characters after `php` , so i would get:

`haysta`

How can i do that?

Greetings

Comment: Do you want the space between php and haystack, returning `[space]hayst`, or the first 6 non-space characters, `haysta`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have just to find the position of `'php'` and then add do a `substr()` on that position +3 (for skipping the `'php'` itself):

```
$needle = 'php';
$str = substr($string, strpos($string, $needle) + strlen($needle), 6);
```

The third parameter (`6`) is the length of the substring you want.

Comment: Having a static value (+3) and 'php' don't make this dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

This approach would allow you to have different seed strings.... to look 'after'

```
$seedString = "php";

$sub= substr($string,strpos($string,$seedString)+strlen($seedString),6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
<?php

$string = 'foo bar php haystack needle';

$snippet = substr($string,12,5);

echo $snippet;

?>
```

Comment: probably the intent is to search the string for php, and then begin the substring from there.  12 as a hardcoded value is a good clue, but i'm guessing not the intent.

Comment: Oh OK, you didn't put that on the spec sheet :).