# Get only the next 6 characters after a string and loop the code to get them all

Tags: php

I found this link useful

[Get only the next 6 characters after a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948101/get-only-the-next-6-characters-after-a-word/37219955#37219955)

but how to make it loop on the entire page using "foreach"

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/news/page'; 
$needle = '<div class="title"><a  href="http://www.example.com/news/'; 
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$str = substr($contents, strpos($contents, $needle) + strlen($needle), 6);
```

this code result `123456` as the id for the first found...

How to make it loop the entire page?

Comment: Don't parse a HTML content like that. It will be a never ending story of things that don't get matched because of an extra space, a single quote instead of a double, an attribute that suddenly appears in one of these tags where you did not expect it, ... Use the DOM capabilities instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice against doing this with `strpos`, because the file may have slight variations of the HTML you are looking for, with an extra space here and there, or a line break, an extra attribute, ...etc.

The way to parse HTML is by using the DOM. In PHP this is done with the DOMDocument class:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/news/page'; 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// ignore errors due to malformed HTML at URL
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@class='title']/a[starts-with(@href, 'http://www.example.com/news/')]");
$href="";
foreach ($elements as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    break; // only the first has our interest
};
// At this point $href is the full href content.
// Split the URL in parts by "/", and get the part that interests us
$num = explode("/", $href)[4]; // adapt "4" to get the right part

echo $num; // 123456
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond:
I mentioned in the $needle the following line
`<div class="title"><a  href="http://www.example.com/news/`
as this is what I'm looking in the code, and the URL is http://www.example.com/news/123456, which the **123456** I'm looking forward to get out...

Comment: I got this error 95 times according to the original page list I'm getting url from:
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://www.example.com/news/page, line: 102 in /home/user/public_html/appfeed/index.php on line 46...

and at last it gave me the id >> 123456/page-title-bla-bla-bla
I want only the exact 6 **123456**carachters after the url: http://www.example.com/news/123456/page-title-bla-bla-bla

Comment: The error means the HTML you read is malformed. You can ignore such errors with `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`. It seems you want a part of the URL that is delimited by slashes. I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks a lot for already having accepted it.